# Can a system that cannot be stabilized with full state feedback be still stabilizable?

Tags: control-theory

The system,
$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 2
\end{array}\right] \mathbf{x}(t)+\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
0
\end{array}\right] u
$$
with the same control approach
$$
A_{c l}=A-B K=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 2
\end{array}\right]-\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
0
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ll}
k_{1} & k_{2}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1-k_{1} & 1-k_{2} \\
0 & 2
\end{array}\right]
$$
so that
$$
\operatorname{det}\left(s I-A_{c l}\right)=\left(s-1+k_{1}\right)(s-2)=0
$$
So the feedback control can modify the pole at $s=1$, but it cannot
move the pole at $s=2$.

cannot be stabilized with full state feedback, and the determinant of its controllability matrix is 0. Hence it is not controllable either.

But can it still be stabilizable? - Maybe using something else than full state feedback.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site, rather than supplying links to images.  You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if
you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). In
 particular, what have you tried so far (or what formulas have your tried to use
), and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want
to see that you have put some thought into the problem.

Comment: I saw a talk (given about 16 years ago) about something called chaos control.  The idea there was to give the heart just a little electrical tap at just the right time and it would set the state of the heart rotating about a different strange attractor (from tachycardia back to a sinus rhythm) .  If you look up articles using the keywords "chaos control" and "strange attractor"  you might get somewhere.  I think this article might be the research I saw https://academic.oup.com/cardiovascres/article/40/2/257/353759/Chaos-in-the-cardiovascular-system-an-update

Comment: The answer is no. Note that for the second state you have $\dot{x}_2=2x_2$ with solution that grows exponentially $x_2(t)=e^{2t}x_2(0)$ that cannot be changed by any selection of the control $u$.

Comment: @CTNT: Can you give more details on your answer. For linear feedback your answer is obvious but what about nonlinear feedback? I was thinking about a nonlinear $u$ that drives $x_1$ and $x_2$ to zero. But I was not able to come up with an example.

Comment: @MrYouMath I am not sure what you are asking, do you mean a linear system and a nonlinear feedback?

Comment: @CTNT: I mean the case of nonlinear feedback. Can we also exclude controllability for a nonlinear control law?

Comment: @MrYouMath Yes,  it is not possible. If the system is not controllable then there exists a decomposition (state transformation) into  a controllable and a non-controllable part. The non-controllable part has its own dynamics and cannot be influenced by the control law and/or the controllable states. Kind like $x_2$ in the above example.